# "No route to host" error in torch.distributed.init_process_group

Tags: pytorch

I'm trying to train a simple pytorch model on two GPU servers in parallel. I have compiled pytorch from source. The program gives the "RuntimeError: No route to host" when the process runs on the second server. How do I fix it?

I have tried the anaconda installation and source installation of pytorch, cuda, NCCL.

I have copied the following code from https://yangkky.github.io/2019/07/08/distributed-pytorch-tutorial.html

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime
import argparse
import torch.multiprocessing as mp
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.distributed as dist
#from apex.parallel import DistributedDataParallel as DDP
#from apex import amp

class ConvNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes=10):
        super(ConvNet, self).__init__()
        self.layer1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(1, 16, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(16),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        )
        self.layer2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(16, 32, kernel_size=5, stride=1, padding=2),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)
        )
        self.fc = nn.Linear(7*7*32, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.layer1(x)
        out = self.layer2(out)
        out = out.reshape(out.size(0), -1)
        out = self.fc(out)
        return out

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-n', '--nodes', default=1, type=int, metavar='N')
    parser.add_argument('-g', '--gpus', default=1, type=int, help='number of gpus per node')
    parser.add_argument('-nr', '--nr', default=0, type=int, help='ranking within the nodes')
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', default=2, type=int, metavar='N', help='number of total epochs to run')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    args.world_size = args.gpus * args.nodes
    os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = '192.168.0.238'
    os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '8888'
    mp.spawn(train, nprocs=args.gpus, args=(args,))

    #train(0, args)

def train(gpu, args):
    rank = args.nr * args.gpus + gpu
    dist.init_process_group(
            backend='nccl',
            init_method='env://',
            world_size=args.world_size,
            rank=rank
            )
    model = ConvNet()
    print('gpu:', gpu)
    torch.cuda.set_device(gpu)
    model.cuda(gpu)
    batch_size= 100

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss().cuda(gpu)
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), 1e-4)

    model = nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(model, device_ids=[gpu])

    train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root='./data',
                                              train=True,
                                              transform=transforms.ToTensor(),
                                              download=True)

    train_sampler = torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSample(
            train_dataset,
            num_replicas=args.world_size,
            rank=rank
            )

    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset,
                                              batch_size=batch_size,
                                              shuffle=False,
                                              num_workers=0,
                                              pin_memory=True,
                                              sampler=train_sampler)

    start = datetime.now()
    total_step = len(train_loader)
    for epoch in range(args.epochs):
        for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
            images = images.cuda(non_blocking=True)
            labels = labels.cuda(non_blocking=True)

            outputs = model(images)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

            if (i+1) % 100 == 0 and gpu == 0:
                print('Epoch [{}/{}], Step [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}'.format(
                    epoch + 1,
                    args.epochs,
                    i + 1,
                    total_step,
                    loss.item()
                ))

    if gpu == 0:
        print("Training complete in:" + str(datetime.now() - start))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR

This may be caused by the firewall.

Follow https://serverfault.com/a/890421 to trust your slave node.

### A step-by-step checklist:

**1. Install the `netcat` to help us check the network**

For Ubuntu:

`apt-get install netcat`

**2. Check if your master process is available**

On **`node0`** (or the master node):

`nc -vv localhost:<port>`

The output `Connection to localhost <port >port [tcp/tproxy] succeeded!` means your main process is running correctly. Otherwise, check if your program on the master node is running correctly.

**3. Close the Firewall**
If the master node program is working, and two nodes are supposed to connect well, this may be a firewall issue. For **firewalld**, consider set your node as `trusted` zone. See https://serverfault.com/a/890421 for more details.